# Getting Soft 404 pages in Netsuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0, suitecommerce, sca

I have been working as a netsuite suitecommerce advanced platform and recently I get noticed that some of the page requests going in the network tab is giving 200 status code return even when the page is not found.

How to return status code as 404 in SCA if the page is not found.